# Mitigate credential leaks via memory dumps in Java

Tags: java, security, memory-dump

We all know that passwords/credentials in Java shall be stored as char array. Its mitigation, not protection.

I always keep my credentials not using immutable objects but soon or later I need to pass it to some class that expects String (from all the 3rd libraries we use). Isn't all the effort gone then?
For example: if I want to set authorization header, the header value is stored as String by org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader class.
Another example (may be not that good): I use a service that deals with passwords (stores them or something else). It requires them as body in the POST request. I create HttpPost and add StringEntity as body. Its already stored as String and can be dumped again.

Do you manage to keep your credentials relatively safe from memory dumps?

Thanks

Comment: If someone has local access to your process then they are king and will be able to see whatever they want. The only thing you can do is slow them down by obfuscating what they might want to look at.

Comment: @xtratic Your comment would make a fine Answer. Then this Question could be closed.

Comment: 3rd party libraries are the issue (potentially)...If you are serious about the memory security of your passwords you won't use any 3rd party libraries that violate that security.  If development speed/cost is your priority than use away and don't worry about this particular layer of security.  You have to choose your priorities based on the type of application you are building.  Are you building a password manager?  If yes, you need to care if your program is exposing credentials in memory... Something less critical maybe not...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help!
Regarding @xtratic comment. My questions was rather you succeed to manage this rule in production. I prefer not to discuss whether its pointless or not, excuse me if I was not clear.
Regarding DarkMatter, thanks for your time, your answer is more detailed. I am not sure whether there is corporation where people do not use 3rd party libs at all. After all my example is with a very widely used component. In the concrete case I talk about business software, not password manager, but I think this does not matter that much.

Comment: Btw, why did the question got minues one? Did I use wrong component or I made unclear question, what might be wrong with such a question. Or someone that does not understand it gave -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting some security experts in the field, I got the following answer:

1. Storing credentials as char[] in Java is a second level of defence. The first one is not to allow them make a memory dump.
2. If the first level is passed we can mitigate how much credentials they will find in the memory.
3. Not using 3rd party libraries is almost impossible nowadays. However in all of my examples the 3rd party libraries have reference to my password for a short period of time. The fact they store it as String does not mean we should not store it properly. We must aim to not store credentials as Strings especially in caches or other places where a reference to that object is hold for a long time.